# Rule of thumb in Dividing CSS into Layout and Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to separate my layout CSS from my theme CSS. However, I am kind of not sure exactly where certain properties such as padding, margin, width, or height belong too. I can see them belonging to either file. Was wondering what is the general rule of thumb for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working on a similar framework (based on [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/)), where we divided layout and visual styles. The distinction we worked from was as follows:

> Anything concerning layout, position, grid etc. goes in "layout". Basically anything related to the box model (height, width, padding, border etc.) plus float, position and some CSS3 layout properties.
> Everything else are visual styles, and belong to other partials.

I highly recommend reading [Jonathan Snook's SMACSS](http://smacss.com/), which is a good starting point for a CSS style guide.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, there is not a hard rule that you have to follow . But it depends like for examle in Visual studio its different and in Drupal its different. but basics are same

- Core CSS  -  rules consist of styling for HTML elements only, such as used in a CSS reset or Normalize.css.
- Layout - arrangement of elements on the page, including grid systems.
- Theme - purely visual styling, such as border, box-shadow, colors and backgrounds, font properties, etc

And you can place them in different CSS files and [Here is the link](https://drupal.org/node/1887918#separate-concerns) , you can read more about the CSS architecture (for Drupal 8), it will give you an basic idea